# Sending an Email in php - \r\n wont split it up

Tags: php, email

I have this PHP Script to send an email to myself.

```
<?php
try {
    $to = "myself@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Test Mail";
    $message = $_GET['mail'];
    $from = "someoneelse@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Mail Sent.";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

As you may see the message is grabbed from the url:
/uploadscript.php?mail=test Message\r\nTest message 2

But the email comes as

```
 Test MessageTest message 2
```

Is it possible to make it actually split it up so it comes as

```
 Test Message
 Test Message 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
function translateCharacters($str){
    return nl2br(str_replace("\\r","\r",
           str_replace("\\n","\n",
           str_replace("\\t","\t",
           $str))));
}
$message = translateCharacters($_GET['mail']);
```

This will convert `\r`, `\n`, `\t` to **`CR`**, **`LF`**, **`TAB`**.

Comment: Why use this & not `nl2br();`?

Comment: @DarylGill : That doesn't convert `"\\n"` to `"\n"`, it converts `"\n"` to "<br/>\n".  It wouldn't do the whole job, but it's worth adding.

Comment: Well. I just ran `echo "This is an \\n example";` in a test page, and the returns was: `This is an \n example`.. From that alone it backs up when I say `\\n` is an escaped new line break, used to display `\n` in the browser in double inverted quotes

Comment: @DarylGill : His GET request has `"Bla Bla\\nMore Bla"`.  I then translate that to `"Bla Bla\nMore Bla"` and run `nl2br` on that, returning `"Bla Bla<br/>\nMore Bla"`, which is what is needed to send in the e-mail.  Am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

FYI - If you're using $_GET for your message - that's pretty dangerous (think about the security of your site)

Regardless: the easiest way is to use urlencoding for new lines.

The urlencode for a new line is `%0A`

PHP already supports [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/urlencode)

```
$message = urlencode($_GET['mail']);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If using values directly from the $_GET value, you should look into: 
    `urlencode();` and `urldecode();`

2) Instead of making new functions, don't re-invent the wheel. Look into `nl2br();`